# Python: How to retrieve second word from the text

Tags: python

So the generator function generates a word char by char until "" and now I want the main function to call out generator function 100 times so that it would create a list words with 100 words. As I have it now it will call out the function 100x but only with one word. What should I do so that it would remember the words it has used already.

```
word = " "
def generator():
    global word
    with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
        file.read(1)
        for line in file:
            for char in line:
                if char != " ":
                    word += char
                if char == " ":
                    return

def main():
    words = []
    for i in range(100):
        generator()
        words.append(word)
    print(words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Im not sure you understand what a generator is ...

Comment: emm... I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: a generator generates sequential responses ... one per `next()` (which is handled implicitly in a `for x in y` statement, and also by using the `yield` keyword) ... this just reads in a file to the first space and stores it in a global variable

Comment: Right. That's not a generator, just a parser.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I think you're confused by the lack of markup in the post. He didn't say it was "a generator function", but rather that it was "the `generator` function". :)

Comment: its not even a parser ... it just repeatedly grabs the first word in a file ... (or not even that if the file starts with a space)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def word_generator():
    word = ""
    with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
        file.read(1)
        for line in file:
            for char in line:
                if char != " ":
                    word += char
                if char == " ":
                    yield word
                    word = ""
```

that is now a generator

it is used like this

```
for word in word_generator():
   print word
```

if you only want the first hundred you could do

```
for i,word in enumerate(word_generator()):
    if i > 100: 
      break
    print word
print "Last Word:",word
```

Comment: But how could I limit the words only to 100?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generator with `yield`, and manipulate the generator as you needed (say stop at 100).

```
def make_generator():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                yield word

def main():
    words = []
    generator = make_generator()
    for i in range(100):
        w = next(generator)
        words.append(w)
    print(words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```